# How to get list of words for each topic for a specific relevance metric value (lambda) in pyLDAvis?

Tags: nlp, gensim, lda, topic-modeling, pyldavis

I am using pyLDAvis along with gensim.models.LdaMulticore for topic modeling. I have totally 10 topics. When I visualize the results using pyLDAvis, there is a bar called lambda with this explanation: "Slide to adjust relevance metric". I am interested to extract the list of words for each topic separately for lambda = 0.1. I cannot find a way to adjust lambda in the document for extracting keywords.

I am using these lines:

```
if 1 == 1:
    LDAvis_prepared = pyLDAvis.gensim_models.prepare(lda_model, corpus, id2word, lambda_step=0.1)
LDAvis_prepared.topic_info
```

And these are the results:

```
   Term     Freq        Total       Category logprob loglift
321 ra      2336.000000 2336.000000 Default 30.0000 30.0000
146 may     1741.000000 1741.000000 Default 29.0000 29.0000
66  doctor  1310.000000 1310.000000 Default 28.0000 28.0000
```

First of all these results are not related to what I observe with lambda of 0.1 in visualization. Secondly I cannot see the results separated by the topics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to read this github page:
https://nicharuc.github.io/topic_modeling/

According to this example, your code could go like this:

```
lambd = 0.6 # a specific relevance metric value

all_topics = {}
num_topics = lda_model.num_topics 
num_terms = 10 

for i in range(1,num_topics+1): ## Indecies are 1-based, not 0-based
    topic = LDAvis_prepared.topic_info[LDAvis_prepared.topic_info.Category == 'Topic'+str(i)].copy()
    topic['relevance'] = topic['loglift']*(1-lambd)+topic['logprob']*lambd
    all_topics['Topic '+str(i)] = topic.sort_values(by='relevance', ascending=False).Term[:num_terms].values
pd.DataFrame(all_topics).T
```